# Ссылка на столбик в таблице бд

Tags: php

Когда пользователь регается, у него появляется профиль, и при нужде его нужно вытянуть, но  для каждого пользователя создавать отдельную страницу невыгодно, вопрос: как вывести профиль каждого пользователя, не создавая новой страницы на фтп.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Специально для тебя - пример...

делаешь страничку users.php, или там profile.php и т.д., там пишешь что-то типа

```
if(isset($_GET['login']) && is_string($_GET['login'])) {
    $login = $_GET['login'];

    //  тут делаешь подключение к БД

    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE login="' . $login . '"';
    $dbResult = mysql_query($query);
    $userProfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult);

    if($userProfile) { // если профиль не пустой, читай если есть пользователь
         // здесь уже как-то отображаешь
         // по нормальному тут подключается шаблон.
         // чисто для примера выведем имя и email
         echo '<h1>логин '. $userProfile['name']  .'</h1>';
         echo '<h1>email '. $userProfile['email'] .'</h1>'; 
         exit();
    }
}

//   если профиль пустой делаем 404
include_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'путь_к_твоей_404.html' );
```

Вот примерно как-то так...
Ну теперь отдаешь в url типа users.php?login=prikol и, если есть такой пользователь - видешь нашу страничку...

Comment: йеееее=) вы лучший как и knes =)

Comment: в get'е передавать имя пользователя... да вы извращенец...

Comment: а как вы предлагаете, POST'om? xDDD

или HEAR'ом ^.^

@kemerov4anin - а как бы передавали вы? Мне бееезумно интересно